# Swift: Become First Responder on UITextField Not Working?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uitextfield, becomefirstresponder

I've created a custom UIViewController with one UITextField on Storyboard. On `viewDidLoad`, I set the UITextFIeld to `becomeFirstResponder`, nothing happened (no keyboards popped up).

I then tried calling `resignFirstResponder()`, but it returned false. Next I tried to find who the `first responder` is through looping all the subviews using the code over @ [Get the current first responder without using a private API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823317/get-the-current-first-responder-without-using-a-private-api). It turns out none of the sub views are the first responder.

My ViewController in storyboard

[image]

My Code

```
class BLTestViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var tf: UITextField

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tf.delegate = self
        tf.becomeFirstResponder()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
```

As simple as it gets...WHY ISN'T THE KEYBOARD COMING UP!!! One thing I do have on is auto layout, but I'm not sure if that affects the keyboard popping up.

Comment: Try making your text field the first responder in `viewWill/DidAppear:`.

Comment: Tried both, no luck.

Comment: Is the text field connected to your view controller with an outlet connection?

Comment: quick idea, I think you may still be calling it too early in viewDidAppear etc... just to test can you set up button that calls a method containing tf.becomeFirstResponder() --- this way we can rule out timing as a problem

Comment: Yes the textField is connected as an IBOutlet. I tried putting `tf.becomeFirstResponder()` in `func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool` which is where I ultimately want to be and is later than `viewDidAppear`, but got a "BAD Access Exception.

Comment: Are you testing in the simulator? Keyboard doesn't appear in simulator in beta 4 for me. Running on device shows it though.

Comment: Yes I'm running on the simulator, I'm trying to run it on the device, but it saids "No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version..." i just updated to the latest iOS version with my iPhone 5.

Comment: The problem only appears on Xcode 6 b5 with the iPhone 4s simulator. This code works well for the iPhone 5s simulator. You should file a radar.

Comment: Side note: you shouldn't call `becomeFirstResponder()` from within `textFieldShouldBeginEditing()`

Comment: @Eugene. I think you're right, this seems to be an issue with the xCode 6 simulator itself!!! God dammit Apple.

Comment: @bennett It appears that there's quite an easy way to bring the keyboard up anyway. Select the text field you'd like to edit in the simulator and press command+k

Comment: See [this question][1]. Basically press Apple+K


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24420873/swift-xcode-6-keyboard-not-showing-up-in-ios-simulator

Comment: Sorry it didn't work for you, but your code worked great for me. +1

Comment: look at this [solution][1], it'll help ;)


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24420873/swift-xcode-6-keyboard-not-showing-up-in-ios-simulator

Comment: try before canFirstResponder before, becomeFirstResponder.

Answer (score 25):

Swift 4 it worked for me

try it

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    
    textView.becomeFirstResponder()
    
}
```

Comment: Executing from inside dispatch queue did it for me.

Comment: `viewDidAppear` is ran on the main thread, ie **delaying** is what's needed, not dispatching to **main**. If you're already on main thread and then dispatch to main, then whatever that you've just dispatched will go to the end of the main queue. I suppose: `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async{}` would also fix the issue, due to the delay it creates. A view must have a Window before it becomes the responder, and that can only happen **after** viewcontroller's  `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` is called. So any attempt to make a view the responder before is overridden

Answer (score 21):

I just tested it with a textfield by calling `self.tf.becomeFirstResponder()` indside `viewDidLoad()` function and its working absolutely fine. You'll need to toggle your keyboard by pressing **command + K** as nflacco just pointed out and disable the hardware keyboard in the simulator as:

1. iOS Simulator -> Hardware -> Keyboard
2. Uncheck "Connect Hardware Keyboard"

Answer (score 6):

I think

```
class BLTestViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet var tf: UITextField

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tf.delegate = self
        self.focustf()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    func focustf(){
    self.tf.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Swift 4 and iOS 11

In my case, no mater what I tried, I was not able to set first responder until I tried this.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if cell.isKind(of: YOURTABLEVIEWCELL.self) {
        if let yourCell = cell as? YOURTABLEVIEWCELL{
            yourCell.yourUiTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone stuck with the same problem.

Comment: in my case i need to focus on custom header section textfield when the user click the row of the section. is it possible? I tried to put the same way in did select row at index path but its not working for me.!

Comment: @HariNarayanan , might try similar to above but with tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int)

Comment: This works when trying to set first responder to a textfield in a table view cell. Even calling it after a 5 second delay in ViewDidLoad did not properly bring up the keyboard. But first responder sets properly from this method.

Comment: You saved my whole workday. Thanks! I've been setting firstResponder in func cell(at _: IndexPath, for tableView: UITableView), but that did not work.

Answer (score 4):

Try setting it after a delay:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
    textField.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

sometimes the wrong is the time in render the view

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the iOS Simulator, press <kbd>⌘ command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> to open the keyboard.