# Cursor already in the TextField when the view is changed

Tags: keyboard, cursor, textfield

I'm new on Swift and I have a question. 
Introduction:
View1-> a view with a button that when clicked goes to view2
View2-> a view with a text field

When I go to View2,to start writing I have to click in the text field. I want that when I change the view1 to view2, the cursor is already in text field ready to write with the keyboard up.
So do you guys no how i can do it?
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting in second view controller under viewdidload function the below code

```
textfield.textAlignment = .left
```

for the keyboard

```
textfield.becomeFirstResponder()
```

Try looking at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27417447/4056108)

or you can follow this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7QANXWdeHAo)