# Using a textView and ScrollView in the same ViewController does not work? Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, uiscrollview, parse-platform, uitextview

I am having a very strange problem.

I have a tableView, which when the cell is clicked it segues to the next VC, sending the data from that cell with it via prepareForSegue function. From the next VC I then segue from there to another VC (again passing the data needed via prepareForSegue). The final VC is a chat style VC, so it contains a scrollView and a textView, the three VCs look like so:  [image]

In the chatViewController I have set up a Parse backend so it queries the data and then places inside the scrollView like so:

[image]

The problem I am having is that the keyboard does not pop open. I know the code is CORRECT! As it pops open when I make the chatViewController the initial VC. it just doesn't work when it is segued to from multiple VC.

Does anybody have any ideas on this or ever had any problems with segueing into a scrollViewController. I've tried everything I can think off.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on ios simulator, the software keyboard may be turned off. **For actual emulation you may try a ios phone instead of simulator**.

If you wanna appear the soft-keypad in simulator try following

**solution**

- iOS Simulator -> Hardware -> Keyboard
- Uncheck "Connect Hardware Keyboard"
  Mine was checked because I was using my mac keyboard, but if you make sure it is unchecked the iPhone keyboard will always come up.

solution is actually copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24420873/xcode-6-keyboard-does-not-show-up-in-simulator)

Comment: It's none of these. Tried all the basic things. It must be some sort of bug just hoping someone has had something similar.

Comment: Have you tried a physical phone ? ios simulators are full of surprises (bugs) with the latest releases :)

Comment: I havent signed up yet. I'll be sure to try that thou. thanks.

Comment: In the meantime you can just press cmd k to bring up the keyboard in the simulator

Comment: Thats exactly what my problem is. The keyboard does not pop up. But when I make the chatViewController the initial VC, it does work. I is something to do with the segue which is effecting the keyboard popping up?