# how to make a toolbar side up Keyboard

Tags: objective-c

I have a toolbar and made this code to learn how to put it above the keyboard when I open it however after doing this or the keyboard appears.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIToolbar *toolbar;


@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.textField.delegate = self;
    self.toolbar.delegate = self;
    self.textField.inputAccessoryView = self.toolbar;

    self.textField.inputView = self.toolbar;
    [self.toolbar removeFromSuperview];
    [self.textField becomeFirstResponder];

}

- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{


    self.textField.inputAccessoryView = self.toolbar;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line `[self.toolbar removeFromSuperview];` is causing the toolbar to become `nil`, so it is not appearing.

And as @jammycoder said you only need to set `inputAccessoryView` of the text field. So do as he suggested and remove the line `self.textField.inputView = self.toolbar;`

**Edit**

I have setup a simple project and put a `UIToolbar` and a `UITextView` on the view controller, in the storyboard. Those two views are connected (IBOutlets) to the ViewController as you *probably* did,.

If I use your code it indeed does not show the keyboard, why? Because you are assigning the `inputView` of the `UITextView`.

So let's debug your code. First of all add bunch of `NSLog` statements like this.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.textField.delegate = self;

    NSLog(@"1 %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.toolbar.frame));
    self.textField.inputAccessoryView = self.toolbar;

    NSLog(@"2 %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.toolbar.frame));
    self.textField.inputView = self.toolbar;

    NSLog(@"3 %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.toolbar.frame));
    [self.toolbar removeFromSuperview];

    NSLog(@"4 %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.toolbar.frame));
    [self.textField becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    NSLog(@"5 %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.toolbar.frame));
    self.textField.inputAccessoryView = self.toolbar;

    NSLog(@"6 %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.toolbar.frame));
}
```

This will print something like:

```
2015-05-14 00:13:46.313 ToolbarKeyboard[8367:4583306] 1 {{0, 524}, {320, 44}}
2015-05-14 00:13:46.314 ToolbarKeyboard[8367:4583306] 2 {{0, 524}, {320, 44}}
2015-05-14 00:13:46.314 ToolbarKeyboard[8367:4583306] 3 {{0, 524}, {320, 44}}
2015-05-14 00:13:46.315 ToolbarKeyboard[8367:4583306] 4 {{0, 524}, {320, 44}}
2015-05-14 00:13:46.491 ToolbarKeyboard[8367:4583306] 5 {{0, 0}, {320, 0}}
2015-05-14 00:13:46.491 ToolbarKeyboard[8367:4583306] 6 {{0, 0}, {320, 0}}
```

So, we discovered that, somehow, your bar height became 0. And, to be honest I don't know why, but lets continue our debugging.

As pointed by @jammycoder you *don't* need to the the `inputView` of the `UITextView` you only need to do that if you want a custom keyboard. So lets change our code to be like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.textField.delegate = self;

    NSLog(@"1 %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.toolbar.frame));
    self.textField.inputAccessoryView = self.toolbar;

    NSLog(@"2 %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.toolbar.frame));
    [self.toolbar removeFromSuperview];

    NSLog(@"3 %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.toolbar.frame));
    [self.textField becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    NSLog(@"4 %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.toolbar.frame));
    self.textField.inputAccessoryView = self.toolbar;

    NSLog(@"5 %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.toolbar.frame));
}
```

This will print that the height of the toolbar remained unchanged. And the toolbar is being shown above the keyboard.

Until here I was using a real device to debug, decided to use a simulator. Wait, it is not opening the keyboard there! It seems to be a new *feature* of Xcode 6, so I did a quick search and found this stackoverflow: [Xcode 6: Keyboard does not show up in simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24420873/xcode-6-keyboard-does-not-show-up-in-simulator) Did what was saying in the most voted answer and the everything is working just fine.

So, in short. The following minimum code will produce the desired behavior. And if you are using the simulator to test/debug it make sure to do what is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24497773/3927536

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIToolbar *toolbar;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.textField.inputAccessoryView = self.toolbar;
    [self.textField becomeFirstResponder];
}

@end
```

Comment: He not decided yet.I do not know what it I did wrong. Now I added a setFrame but still not working. Thank you for your help!

Comment: This is the right answer. You've declared your toolbar as `weak` therefore when you `removeFromSuperView` it is released. If you want to keep it around, declare it as `strong` and don't remove from super view. Adding it as a sub view to another view will remove it from the previous view.

Answer (score 0):

This line brings up the keyboard

```
    [self.textField becomeFirstResponder];
```

When a textfield becomes first responder it automatically brings up the keyboard.

**Edit**: remove the following line

```
self.textField.inputView = self.toolbar;
```

You only need to set the toolbar as `inputAccessoryView`

**Edit2**: also remove this line

```
[self.toolbar removeFromSuperview];
```

Comment: continues without opening the keyboard

Comment: What are you wanting to happen??

Comment: I want to open a toolbar above my keyboard. The problem is that after I configured the tollbar neither she nor the keyboard appear. The toolbar in this same storyboard textField that will open the keyboard

Comment: If you tap on the textfield do they both appear?

Comment: No. None of them appears. You have no idea what can be? I'm with this problem to three hours already. It is the first time I have an application using the tollbar

Comment: Even so. The problem is not this this line. I do not have to use a toolbar that is in a separate place from the storyboard?

Comment: Try not removing the toolbar

Comment: He not decided yet.I do not know what it I did wrong. Now I added a setFrame but still not working. Thank you for your help!