# Keyboard not showing for UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I have a UIView that contains a `UICollectionView`, which contains custom cells. These custom cells contain a `UILabel` and a `UITextField`. The code for the custom cell class and the `UICollectionView` one of the delegate methods is:

```swift
class DurationDayCells: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var dayLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var dayHourText: UITextField!
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return daysSet.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!,layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout!,sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGSize {

    return CGSize(width: (self.durationCollectionView.frame.width/CGFloat(daysSet.count)), height:
        self.durationCollectionView.frame.height)

}
```

So as you can see, these cells are dynamically created and sized according to the size of `daysSet`. The problem is when I tap one of the text fields in the cells the keyboard does not pop up (the pink/red view is the said `UIView`):

[image: screenshot1]

I also have a follow up question for when I did manage to make the keyboard show (somehow), it blocked the pink/red `UIView` completely, is there a way to move the whole `UIView` up when a text field is selected so the keyboard does not block it?

Answer (score 12):

About the keyboard not showing up, the simulator might be set to link your computer's keyboard. From [Xcode 6: Keyboard does not show up in simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24420873/xcode-6-keyboard-does-not-show-up-in-simulator)

iOS Simulator -> Hardware -> Keyboard

Uncheck "Connect Hardware Keyboard"

For getting an easy way to have your content scroll up automatically when a keyboard shows, the CocoaPod IQKeyboard is built just for this https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

If you don't know what CocoaPods are, I strongly suggest checking them out at https://cocoapods.org/