# UIKeyboard not appearing when tapping on UITextField in my app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4.1

In my app I have some UITextFeilds but when I run my app and trying to write I can't see the keyboard.

[image]

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24497773/10326766) answer, but probably my xcode version isn't the same as there, I'm using xcode9.

[image]

Comment: If you are using simulator, try **Command  +  K**

Comment: I need to do this every time? I want a "real" demo when I build my app

Comment: If you do it once, it'll be there always. If you do it again, it will disappear until you do it again.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri ok thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on simulator just see on the top menu and go :-

```
Hardware -> keyboard -> Toggle Software Keyboard
```

Comment: Can't see `Hardware`  in Xcode9

Comment: click on your simulator or iphone then you will find simulator menu on top

Answer (score 0):

To toggle the software keyboard In the **Simulator** app tap : <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>

Or go to the **Hardware** menu (in the simulator app) :

[image: Hardware menu]

And choose **Keyboard** and then **Toggle the Software Keyboard** :

[image]

Comment: As you can see in my question in the picture, I don't have `Hardware` tab.

Comment: @trycatch it is three menus to the right.

Comment: You are right..

Comment: @trycatch Glad I could help!

Comment: @trycatch It's up 