# React Native-Keyboard is not showing up

Tags: keyboard, react-native, react-native-ios

I am learning React-Native and am having trouble getting the keyboard to pop up to enter text.

I have tried looking through multiple docs and questions but can not seem to find a solution. I tried to change the `componentDidMount` function multiple times in order to try and make the keyboard pop up.

Here is the Full File

```py
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import {Image, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Text, TextInput, ImageBackground, Button, Alert, Keyboard} from 'react-native';
    import {SearchBar} from 'react-native-elements';
    import {createStackNavigator, createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
    const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
        container: { // just for main screen if need be
            flex: 1,
            backgroundColor: '#fff0f5'
        },
        image: { // for time tree logo 
            width: 350,
            height: 450,
            flex: 1,
        },
        words: { // for any text
            margin: 15,
            height: 20,
            borderColor: '#7a42f4',
            borderWidth: 0,
            alignSelf: 'baseline',
            fontSize: 20,
            flex: 0
        },
        small: { // random too scared to get rid of
            alignItems: 'baseline',
            flex: 3,
        },
        info: { // for info button
            height: 50,
            width: 50,
            flex: 1,
            position: 'absolute',
            left: 300,
            bottom: 15,
        },
        panel: { // for panel that input stuff will lay on
            height: 200,
            width: 400,
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(4,22,66,0.5)',
            flex: 1,
            position: 'absolute',
            top: 200,
            right: 0,
        },
        boxA:{ // for taxon A
            height: 40,
            width: 200,
            backgroundColor: '#d3d3d3',
            position: 'absolute',
            top: 235,
            right: 150,
            borderRadius: 10,
            flex: 1,
        },
        boxB: { // for taxon B
            height: 40,
            width: 200,
            backgroundColor: '#d3d3d3',
            position: 'absolute',
            top: 315,
            right: 150,
            borderRadius: 10,
            flex: 1,
        },
        searchButton: {
            height: 30,
            width: 80,
            backgroundColor: '#d3d3d3',
            flex: 1,
            position: 'absolute',
            right: 25,
            top: 280,
            borderRadius: 10,
        },
        text: {
            fontSize: 20,
            textAlign: 'center',
        },
    });

    class SearchScreen extends Component<Props>{
        /* Functions for the keyboard */
        componentDidMount() {
            this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener(
                'keyboardDidShow',
                this._keyboardDidShow,
            );
            this.keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener(
                'keyboardDidHide',
                this._keyboardDidHide,
            );
        }
        componentWillUnmount() {
            this.keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
            this.keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
        }

        _keyboardDidShow() {
            alert('Keyboard Shown');
        }

        _keyboardDidHide() {
            alert('Keyboard Hidden');
        }
        /* End of KEyboard Functions */
        /* Functions for the input of the Taxa*/
        constructor(Props){
            super(Props);
            this.state = {taxonA : "", taxonB : ""};
        }
        handleTaxonA = (text) => {
            this.setState({ 
                taxonA : text, 
            });
        }
        handleTaxonB = (text) => {
            this.setState({ 
                taxonB : text, 
            });
        }
        searchHit = (taxonA,taxonB) => { // for debugging
            Alert.alert('Taxon A: '+ this.state.taxonA + '\nTaxon B: ' + this.state.taxonB)
        }
        _onPressButton() { // for debugging
            Alert.alert('You tapped the button!')
        }
        /* End of Input Functions */
        render(){
            return (
                <ImageBackground source = {require('../assets/images/TimeTreeSearch.png')} 
                imageStyle = {{resizeMode: 'contain'}}
                style = {{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}
                >
                    <View style = {styles.panel}/>
                    <View style = {styles.boxA}>
                        <TextInput
                            style = {styles.words}
                            autoCapitalize = 'none'
                            onChangeText = {this.handleTaxonA}
                            placeholderTextColor = 'grey'
                            placeholder = 'Taxon A...'
                            autoFocus = {true}
                        />
                    </View>
                    <View style = {styles.boxB}>
                        <TextInput 
                            style = {styles.words}
                            autoCapitalize = 'none'
                            onChangeText = {this.handleTaxonB}
                            placeholderTextColor = 'grey'
                            placeholder = 'Taxon B...'
                        />
                    </View>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                    style = {styles.searchButton}
                    onPress= {this.searchHit}
                    >
                        <Text style = {styles.text}>Search</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <TouchableOpacity 
                    style = {styles.small}
                    hitSlop = {{top: -750, bottom: 15, right: 50, left: -275}}
                    onPress = {this._onPressButton}
                    >
                        <Image 
                        style = {styles.info}
                        resizeMode = 'contain'
                        source = {require('../assets/images/info2.png')} 
                        />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </ImageBackground>
            );
        }
    }

    export default SearchScreen;
```

I should be getting the keyboard but I am instead getting an alert, I set up that says `Keyboard Hidden` instead.

Comment: Are you using IOS simulator? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24420873/xcode-6-keyboard-does-not-show-up-in-simulator

Comment: Thank you, This was the problem