# keyboard not appear at google signIn page of ios 13

Tags: keyboard, google-signin, swift5, xcode11.3

I am facing issue on login through Google SignIn. Actually not showing keyboard on iOS 13.2.2 at iPhone. Please check below images.[image][image]

Comment: See this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24420873/xcode-6-keyboard-does-not-show-up-in-simulator?rq=1

Comment: Already check this link.

Comment: Hi, currently I'm facing the same problem as above ( not 100% ). Did you resolve this problem?

Comment: @NguyễnHoàngThiênPhước Delete scene delegate from project. after that resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set presentingViewController to window.rootViewController in the SceneDelegate:

```
 let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
 window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)     
 GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().presentingViewController = window.rootViewController       
 self.window = window
 window.makeKeyAndVisible()
```